# CSS - how do i stretch the background of the menu

Tags: css

Hello,

Can someone help me, how can i stretch the background of the menu (to be full width, from left to right)?
I'm a beginner.

Thanks.

```
#menu, #menu ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

#menu {
    width:100%;
    margin: 0px;
    background-color: #3d56ac;
    background-image: linear-gradient(#444, #111);

}

#menu:before,
#menu:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
}

#menu:after {
    clear: both;
}

#menu {
    zoom:1;
}

#menu li {
    float: left;
    border-right: 1px solid #222;
    box-shadow: 1px 0 0 #444;
    position: relative;
}

#menu a {
    float: left;
    padding: 12px 30px;
    color: #FFF;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font: bold 12px Arial, Helvetica;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #111;
}

#menu li:hover > a {
    color: #fafafa;
}

*html #menu li a:hover { /* IE6 only */
    color: #fafafa;
}

#menu ul {
    margin: 20px 0 0 0;
    _margin: 0; /*IE6 only*/
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 38px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;    
    background: #444;   
    background: linear-gradient(#444, #111);
    box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.3);  
    border-radius: 3px;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;  
}

#menu li:hover > ul {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    margin: 0;
}

#menu ul ul {
    top: 0;
    left: 150px;
    margin: 0 0 0 20px;
    _margin: 0; /*IE6 only*/
    box-shadow: -1px 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,.3);      
}

#menu ul li {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    border: 0;
    _line-height: 0; /*IE6 only*/
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #111, 0 2px 0 #666;
}

#menu ul li:last-child {   
    box-shadow: none;    
}

#menu ul a {    
    padding: 10px;
    width: 130px;
    _height: 10px; /*IE6 only*/
    display: block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    float: none;
    text-transform: none;
}

#menu ul a:hover {
    background-color: #0186ba;
    background-image: linear-gradient(#04acec, #0186ba);
}

#menu ul li:first-child > a {
    border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
}

#menu ul li:first-child > a:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 40px;
    top: -6px;
    border-left: 6px solid transparent;
    border-right: 6px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 6px solid #444;
}

#menu ul ul li:first-child a:after {
    left: -6px;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -6px;
    border-left: 0; 
    border-bottom: 6px solid transparent;
    border-top: 6px solid transparent;
    border-right: 6px solid #3b3b3b;
}

#menu ul li:first-child a:hover:after {
    border-bottom-color: #04acec; 
}

#menu ul ul li:first-child a:hover:after {
    border-right-color: #0299d3; 
    border-bottom-color: transparent;   
}

#menu ul li:last-child > a {
    border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
}
```

Comment: Provide image of expectable result

Comment: are you using tables on the menu construction ? if so , add border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"

Comment: Linear gradients and plain background colors should already "stretch" the whole width of the element. Can you give a screenshot of what you get atm?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
#menu {
  background-size: 100%;
}
```

Comment: i've done it with the code from Guarav, but the menu it's not centered now :(

Comment: Centered horizontally or vertically? Try `margin: 0 auto;`

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix the width of the image... if your want to Stretch the background image...

```
**CSS** 
    background-image: url("menu.png");
    background-size: 875px 125px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Hope this will helps you...

**or you can try...**

/css

```
body{margin: 0 auto;}
    .menu100percent {
    background: #3584b4; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3584b4 0%, #25567f 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#3584b4), color-stop(100%,#25567f)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3584b4 0%,#25567f 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3584b4 0%,#25567f 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3584b4 0%,#25567f 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3584b4 0%,#25567f 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#3584b4', endColorstr='#25567f',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    height: 37px;
    width:100%;
}
    .menu{width:1000px; margin: 0 auto; }
    .menu a{color:#fff; font-size:12px; line-height:37px; font-family:Arial; text-decoration:none;}
```

/html

```
<div class="menu100percent">
    <div class="menu">
        <a href="/Purchase.aspx">Shop</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/kksW2/)

Comment: doesn't work....if i change the width, it stretches only in right side.....any other ideas?

`codewidth: 1200px;
 margin: 0px auto;
 border: 1px solid #222;
 background-color: #3d56ac;
 background-image: linear-gradient(#444, #111);
 border-radius: 6px;
 box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #777;`code`